# Formating Mysql query number to return a number of given format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query which finds the difference of two values, Though it returns a round value which is exactly what i do not want

Query :

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(SUM(obq * Rate), 2) - FORMAT(SUM(cbq * Rate), 2) AS variance
FROM
    budget_sheet
WHERE
    project_name = 'Vineyard_Ngong_Villas'
    AND phase = 'Phase_I'
    AND house_no = '002';
```

Results:

First part returns : 26,000.00

Second part        : 42,700.00

difference         :-16  instead of -16,700.00

Comment: remove format function `SELECT SUM(obq * Rate) - SUM(cbq * Rate) AS variance`

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-apply `format` on the difference value.

**Change**:

```
FORMAT( SUM( obq * Rate ), 2 )
- FORMAT( SUM( cbq * Rate ), 2 ) AS variance
```

**To**:

```
FORMAT( FORMAT( SUM( obq * Rate ), 2 )
        - FORMAT( SUM( cbq * Rate ), 2 )
       , 2 ) AS variance
```

***Example***:

```
mysql>  select
    ->   format(16,2) s,
    ->   format(2,2) t,
    ->   format(16,2) - format(2,2) d,
    ->   format( format(16,2) - format(2,2), 2 ) fd;
+-------+------+------+-------+
| s     | t    | d    | fd    |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| 16.00 | 2.00 |   14 | 14.00 |
+-------+------+------+-------+
```